# MPAndroidChart - How can i set the values in BarEntry dynamically?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I can able to do with static content. But when am trying to do with API integration.

1. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException error-How to solve this,

> ATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.eengage.toit, PID: 15219
>                                                                     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.BarBuffer.addBar(BarBuffer.java:37)
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.HorizontalBarBuffer.feed(HorizontalBarBuffer.java:52)
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.HorizontalBarChartRenderer.drawDataSet(HorizontalBarChartRenderer.java:66)
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawData(BarChartRenderer.java:74)
>                                                                         at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:247)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14508)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13405)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14225)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3105)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2942)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13400)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13338)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13447)
>                                                                         at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1577)
>                                                                         at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2407)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2279)
>                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.

2. API integration details-is there any problem with adding the values in to list,

   ```
   class Top10UsersChartDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String response = null;
       try {
           response = apiDetails.Top10UsersChartFunc(params[0], params[1]);
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }
       return response;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       super.onPostExecute(s);

       try {
           JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(s);
           String status = resObj.getString("status");
           String Month = resObj.getString("Month");


               JSONArray userdataDetailsArray = resObj.getJSONArray("userdata");

               for (int j = 0; j < userdataDetailsArray.length(); j++) {
                   JSONObject CampaignDetailsArrayObject = userdataDetailsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                   String userId = CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("userId");
                   String UserName = CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("UserName");
                   String CountRunning = CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("Count");
                   String position=CampaignDetailsArrayObject.getString("position");
                   float fp1 = Float.parseFloat(CountRunning);

                   BARENTRY1.add(new BarEntry(fp1,j));
                   BarEntryLabels1.add("User#"+position);
               }
               horizontalBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
               horizontalBarChart.invalidate();
           } else {
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }

   }
   ```

   }

   3. How can i set the x axis and y axis values.

      BARENTRY1.add(new BarEntry(fp1,j));
                      BarEntryLabels1.add("User#"+position);

here am setting the value,but my x axis and y axis always showing like this and that fp1 value is not setting.Please find the screenshot[image]

Note:

- How can i set x axis and y axis values?
- How can i set BarEntry value?
- How can i change Horizontal Chart Bardataset order in to reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting the x-axis and y-axis first and then give the values to the bar chart. The code below might help you to understand.

This is the axis formatting  class.

```
/**
 * Created by aghatiki on 8/25/2016.
 */
public class MyAxisValueFormatter implements AxisValueFormatter {
    private String[] mValues;
    public MyAxisValueFormatter(String[] values)
    {
        this.mValues = values;
    }
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return mValues[(int) value];
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the class where you add the values to the BarEntry.Please look below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BarChart barChart;
    String[] values = new String[]{"June","July","August","September","October","Novenber"};
    final String[] quarters = new String[] { "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(0f,30f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1f,80f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2f,60f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3f,50f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4f,70f));
        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5f,60f));
        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Dates");

        ArrayList<String> theDates = new ArrayList<>();
        theDates.add("April");
        theDates.add("MAy");
        theDates.add("June");
        theDates.add("July");
        theDates.add("August");
        theDates.add("September");

        BarData theData = new BarData(barDataSet);
        theData.setBarWidth(0.9f);
        barChart.setData(theData);

        barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        barChart.setFitBars(true);
        barChart.setDescription("Test data on the bar");

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyAxisValueFormatter(values));
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    }
}
```

Comment: I can do with static.There is no issues.But when am trying to set through API integration its like that.

Comment: AxisValueFormatter where is the interface class here?

Comment: This interface is present in MPAndroid chart library. @SunishaSindhu

Comment: Am not getting.I think we need to write another interface class

Comment: Ho we can reverse the chart?Because when am trying to reverse the value is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these code below in to

```
horizontalBarChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        horizontalBarChart.invalidate();

Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY1, "Projects");
                BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels1, Bardataset);
                Bardataset.setColors(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#701112")});
                horizontalBarChart.setData(BARDATA);
                horizontalBarChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
                horizontalBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
                horizontalBarChart.setPinchZoom(false);
                horizontalBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                horizontalBarChart.setDescription("");
                Bardataset.setBarSpacePercent(10f);
                Legend legend = horizontalBarChart.getLegend();
                legend.setEnabled(false);
                horizontalBarChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
                XAxis xAxis1 = horizontalBarChart.getXAxis();
                xAxis1.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                xAxis1.setTextSize(8);
                xAxis1.setSpaceBetweenLabels(8);
                xAxis1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#701112"));
                xAxis1.setTypeface(tf);
                YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
```